# Using rosbag c++ code API

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-comm, git, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to use the rosbag C++ code API in my own node.
For that I need to refer to the rosbag sources (rosbag::Bag etc.). By default only the binaries from rosbag were installed. So I cloned the ros_comm git into my local ros stack ros_comm. Now the stack contains the src files, but I still can't refer to them in my eclipse project for the node.

Where do I have to put the source files from rosbag to let Eclipse and the maker recognize them?

One solution would be to include them via their absolute path, but don't feel like this would be a good solution.

Best regards,
Josch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55119/using-rosbag-c++-code-api/) by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosbag package installs not only the binaries but also the header files and the libraries. Just add a dependency on rosbag in your CMakeLists.txt and link against the rosbag library. You should not download the sourcecode and add it manually.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on 2013-02-13**:
I didn't think it would be that easy.
The solution was even more simple: I just had to add the rosbag dependency to my manifest.xml file. Everything working fine now, thanks!

**Comment by [acollins](https://answers.ros.org/users/30672/acollins/) on 2017-06-07**:
Can I get an ELI5? I do "locate CMakeLists.txt" and there are literally hundreds of them. Which one do I add the dependency too?